# Rails partial how to use controller function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With a Rails index view, you can create a matching controller action. For instance a view called `workorders.index2.html.erb`,can have the following controller action:

```
class WorkordersController < ApplicationController
  def index2
    @workorders = Workorder.order("position")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @workorders }
   end
  end
```

But, what if you have a partial called `_mygroupswos.html.erb`.  How can I get the partial to use a matching action in the `workorders` controller?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the usecase for this?

Comment: You're looking at this backwards, URLs -> Controller/Action -> Views. An action will **default** to a view with the same name as the action, but it can actually use any view.

Comment: It looks like you are turning things around conceptually:

The controller makes the call to render a view template. Not the other way around (a view template calling a controller action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails Controller renders the view automatically based on the naming convention. But you can always override it by asking the action to render a different view explicitly.

```
def some_action
   render :partial => "mygroupswos", :layout => true
end
```

partials are generally used for sharing view logic. So I would advice you to create a view template and render the partial there.